# CA Workload Automation ESP on docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, ca

Below is our current application architecture, we are using CA Workload Automation ESP for batch scheduling

[image]

and we are moving to this application to Azure Kubernetes

Application is built on Java tech stack. How do I  configure the CA Workload Automation ESP Agent on the docker Image so that ESP Server can connect and execute the Jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build a custom docker image with CA Workload Automation ESP Agent installed on it before adding your Java application.

Comment: Can you please help me with a sample docker file?

Comment: Do you have the commands to install CA Workload Automation ESP Agent on Linux? If you have those, I can post a Dockerfile that may help you